How to fetch installed app usage data using Device Activity and Family Controls?
I'm trying to create a function in Swift that requests the authorization for the individual and fetch the screen time app usage data of all the installed apps inside iphone device for last 24 hours. I've added the necessary permissions and capabilities.
This is my code:
import UIKit
import DeviceActivity
import FamilyControls
func requestScreenTimeData() {
        Task {
            do {
                try await AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: .individual)
                print("Authorization successful!")
                // Define the filter for activity monitoring
                let endDate = Date() // Current time
                let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -24, to: endDate)!
                let dateInterval = DateInterval(start: startDate, end: endDate)
                
                let activityFilter = DeviceActivityFilter(
                    segment: .daily(during: dateInterval),
                    users: .all,
                    devices: .init([.iPhone])
                    
                )
                
                // Fetch and return the app usage data
                
                
                
            } catch {
                print("Authorization failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

I want to get this data in json or similar form so that i can show it inside my customized UI view.

Have you implemented a device activity report extension?  The boilerplate code that Apple provides when you add the extension target should get you started.

No, I'm trying the swift language for first time as I'm writing my Flutter plugin. Can you help me with this extension because I can't see any working example.
Thanks!

You can get App information, you get an app token. Developers can’t access the specific apps. The extension lets you make a View that the user can see but you won’t get a JSON with the data

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10123

Thanks @Paulw11
Appreciate your help

Open your project in Xcode and add a new target. Select the device activity report extension and you will get a boilerplate implementation
